# cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, typescript1.5

Problem while using visual studio code with angularjs2 and Typescript 1.5beta.

> Error:(3, 1) TS1148: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.
>   Error:(6, 1) TS1205: Decorators are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.

I can run the same code using the commandline compiler using 
tsc -t es5 -m commonjs  app.ts.The same problem occours with webstorm 10.0.2 as well.

Answer (score 11):

This is how I solved it in Webstorm/IntelliJ

File>Settings>Languages & Frameworks > TypeScript

Command Line options:

-m amd -t ES5

Comment: use `-m amd -t ES6` for Ecmascript 6

Answer (score 6):

solved it myself on visual studio code.
steps:

1)tsd init

2)tsd query angular --action install --save

3)create tsconfig.json .The configuration file looks something like this

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}`

but still dont know how to make it work on webstorm

Comment: For more info about `tsconfig.json` see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Comment: In webstorm you can add the commandline option `--module commonjs` in Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript

Comment: on adding commandline option like "--module commonjs" it shows error cannot start compiler procoess

Comment: I had the error "connot start compiler process" too ... but it disappeared after removing any File Watchers and restarting WebStorm ...
I also have added `-t es5` to the command line options...

Comment: In WebStorm 11 (currently in Early Access Preview) you can let WebStorm use the tsconfig.json, so setting the commandline options manually is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error using Visual Studio Code and ng2-meteor.

Not sure if the angular.d.ts created with the 2nd tsd command is needed, but this tsconfig.json seemed to sort things:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "system",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```